# Accessing the value of another array and storing it another array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have two classes Class A and Class B

I want to access the value of an array in Class A and pass that value onto a method in Class B which takes an array as the argument.

I have created a global variable in Class B

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *globalArray;
@synthesize globalArray;
```

In Class A I am using the instance array variable to store the value of the local array.

```
globalArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:localArray];
```

But when I am trying to access the instance array from Class B the count is being shown as 0

In Class B I have the following code

```
[self insertingArrayHere:globalArray]
```

I have already imported the headers but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is `localArray` coming from?

Comment: its coming from a method in Class A

Comment: it's an ivar in Class A?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is impossible to parse in a meaningful way.  Where is "localArray" defined -- which class?  Where are you setting it?  Are you using the SAME INSTANCE of your classes for both setting the value and accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see a lot more code to have a more precise answer, but

From your question I would say that you are not making the distinction between a `class` and an `instance` of a class.

And by this I mean that you are probably creating an instance A1 at some place in your code, then in an other place you are creating an instance A2. And you are wondering why A1 and A2 don't have the same Array in them.
Well the reason is simple : They are 2 different instance (2 different object / 2 different car if you prefer).

Your instance property `globalArray` is not a global variable.

To solution your problem you need to have a look at the `singleton` pattern.